# Sublime Text Compilation Issue

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I've tried searching for this issue but came up empty. Due to the desire to use a better IDE, I installed Sublime Text 3 and Stino. I have installed the Stino package and now have the Arduino menu inside the Sublime Text editor. I have selected the Arduino application folder appropriately. However, when I compile the simple Blink example, I'm presented with the following error. This error comes up when I attempt to compile any Arduino project. Have I forgotten to configure a setting? All videos and tutorials I've seen just follow the same steps as I have and don't seem to include any additional configuration (besides selecting the Arduino application folder).

```
[Stino - Start building "Blink"...]
[  3%] Creating C:\Users\cketc_000\Documents\Arduino\Blink\Blink.ino.cpp.o...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD  -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=161 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\examples\01.Basics\Blink" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\cketc_000\Documents\Arduino\Blink\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\cketc_000\Documents\Arduino\Blink\Blink.ino.cpp.o"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.


[Stino - Exit with error code 1.]
```

Comment: You might need an older version of the IDE. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Majenko I am using Arduino 1.6.1. I noticed in the Arduino forums that some were having trouble with 1.6.2 and suggested reverting back to 1.6.1. I can try with a pre-1.6 version this evening. I receive the same error at compilation with both Sublime Text 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick update for anyone who runs into a similar issue (granted, a week later)...

I upgraded to 1.6.5 of the Arduino IDE, making sure to set my Arduino application folder appropriately, and the compilation issue has disappeared. I am able to compile and upload projects successfully.