# Sublime Text 2 with stino, compilation gives "filename ... is incorrect" Arduino IDE 1.7.8

Tags: arduino-ide

I can't compile a simple blink sketch.

Error is:

```
[Stino - Start building "t5"...]
[  3%] Creating C:\Users\lov\AppData\Local\Temp\Stino_build\t5\t5.ino.cpp.o...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

See also [see similar question, that answer not working here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/sublime-text-compilation-issue).

Path to IDE app is `C:\Program Files (x86)\added\Arduino`.

Comment: Rename the program file to t5.cpp .

Comment: I suggest you do not install into `'C:\Program Files (x86)\added\Arduino'`. Windows does some weird things with that directory, believe me. I usually put it on the desktop or somewhere I have normal write access to.

Comment: I've been working with Sublime Text 3, and trying to get it to work with Arduino IDE 1.8.1.  It has not gone well. From what I've read Stino is not compatible with the IDE beyond 1.6.2 or so, as the IDE library management was completely redone, among other things. I have just gotten that combination [Sublime 3 & IDE 1.6.2] to work ok, but still seem to have some library problems.  As for Stino, it looks like there is a new version in the works, but not complete.  More info on Github.

It you actually succeed, I would like to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this is too big for a comment.

Firstly please can you check the obvious, in Windows Explorer paste the path C:\Users\lov\AppData\Local\Temp\Stino_build\t5 into the address bar and does the directory exist. (I have fallen for that so many times)

Secondly do you have permission to create a file there?

Have you updated the IDE? Does blink compile?

Have you tried running the IDE as admin?

Hopefully one of those will fix it.